# Сумма чисел массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Задачи: есть две переменные ***"a"*** и ***"b"*** необходимо произвести сумму чисел от переменной ***"а"*** до переменной ***"b"***.

> Пример (a =- 1, b = 2) = -1 + 0 + 1 + 2 = 2;

Мой код:

```js
function GetSum(a, b) {
  var numArray = [];
  if (a < b) {
    for (var s = a; s < b; s++) {
      numArray.push(s);
    }
  }
  numArray.push(b);
}

console.log(GetSum(-1, 2));
```

Ответ будет ***"2"***.

Так вот как все таки произвести сумму массива?

Comment: А зачем вообще использовать массив ?

Comment: А где в приведенном коде считается сумма?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для получения суммы на отрезке [a, b] нет необходимости заводить массив, это лишь займет лишнее время.

---

Операция push вставляет за O(1), так забираете n операций.
Потом еще проход по массиву n операций и n операций на суммирование.
Таким образом без массива -2*n операций.
*n = b - a + 1*

Выгоднее просто просуммировать их в одной переменной.

```
function GetSum(a, b){
    var result = 0;
    // if(b < a) b = [a, a = b][0]; // если бывает такой случай
    for(var i = a;i <= b;i++) result += i;
    return result;
}

print(GetSum(2,-1));
```

Comment: Правильный ответ, плюсую :) Для произвольного массива чисел - можно использовать мой метод.

Answer (score 3):

Вы, граждане, совсем уже чувство реальности потеряли:

```js
function sumAllIntegers(start, end) {
  return (end - start + 1) * (start + end) / 2;
}

console.log(sumAllIntegers(-1, 2));
console.log(sumAllIntegers(1, 100), "(привет от маленького Гаусса)");
```

Comment: Господи, адекватный ответ безо всяких циклов... Вот, что бывает, когда люди без какого-либо знания мат.части лезут в программирование ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Ave mathematica!

Answer (score 0):

в конец функции добавьте:

```
return numArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

либо для старых браузеров:

```
return numArray.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить сумма элементов массива можно воспользоваться функцией `reduce`:

```
numArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0)
```

То есть код из примера будет выгладить так:

```
function GetSum( a,b ){
  var numArray=[]; 
  if (a<b){
    for (var s=a;s<b;s++){
      numArray.push(s);
    }
  }
  numArray.push(b);     
  return numArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue, 0)
}
GetSum(-1,2);
```

Также можно обойтись без массива, например:

```
function GetSum( a,b ){
  let accumulator = 0;
    for (let i=a; i<=b; i++){
      accumulator += i;
    }
  return accumulator;
}
```